# Set keep-alive timeout for Flask server with parameter

Tags: python, flask

Is there a possibility to set a **KeepAlive** timeout for a flask server?

I found that post [How to make Flask/ keep Ajax HTTP connection alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523879/how-to-make-flask-keep-ajax-http-connection-alive)? However, I want to give a parameter which is also possible for nginx and apache server such as:

```
app.run(keep_alive_timeout=60)
```

Edit: This question [Are a WSGI server and HTTP server required to serve a Flask app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982807/are-a-wsgi-server-and-http-server-required-to-serve-a-flask-app) didn't answer how to to set an KeepAlive timeout.

Comment: AFAIK, there is none. There is a ticker opened for this, and their response is to use some queuing system. https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1478

Comment: @VigneshSP thanks, do you know if there is an other option to set the timeout?